# PHP PDF library for use with Large complex files

Tags: pdf, php

I am looking for recommendations for a PHP PDF library that is quick to render and can work with complex files. My application is written using the Cake framework. One of our component software packages use mPDF and the way it's configured (maybe the configuration) is that sometimes it chokes.

Comment: What do you mean by "work with"?  Creation/generation, manipulation, searching etc are all different possibilities.  Being more specific might help you get answers.

Comment: Further clarification... this is server side, and is intended as a method for allowing users to download content that has already been rendered on the screen so that it can be used outside of the web app.